# strange behavior accessing DB2 database from VB.NET project

Tags: vb.net, db2, dao

We have a test environment and a production environment with DB2 database and VB.net projects. We have recently added 4 columns to a 74 column table, giving a total of 78 columns. We have had this change in the testing environment for some time, but just added to production yesterday. In our VB.net code (test and prod), we use a `Select * FROM TABLENAME` statement to get a single row from the database and display it. Everything works perfectly in the testing environment but, when we run the code and point to the production database, the four newly added columns are not included in the result, and we get an error when we try to access that data.

Here is where it gets weird. If we explicitly name the new columns in our select statement, they are included, and all is good. I know that we should explicitly name the columns, as a best practice, and that is what we are going to do but, I have to figure out what is happening.

Further observations:

- If I use System i Navigator to enter the `Select * FROM TABLENAME` query into the production database, all the columns are returned, including the 4 new columns.
- We are using the EXACT same VB.NET code to access testing's DB and production's DB... we run the project and just change the connection string from TestingDB to ProductionDB so, we have eliminated the possibility of different data object versions (I think), etc.

So, the columns are there if we use System i Navigator (using `SELECT *`). The columns are there if we explicitly name them in our VB.NET code. But, if we use `Select *` in our VB.NET code, the 4 new columns are excluded (but only in the production version).

Has anyone seen anything like this behavior before?

Comment: Are you directly using SQL in the program, or is this through a stored procedure? Also, what is the error you are getting (SQL Code)?

Comment: thank you for your response. Yes, we are creating the SQL Statement directly in the code...no stored procedure. The error is, basically, "The column doesn't exist" when we try to display the new columns. If we look at the results in the object viewer, the columns aren't there.

Comment: Sounds like sound kind of caching issue.

Comment: How did you add the columns?  If you used ALTER TABLE, did you check that it is complete?

Comment: @Cyborgx37 This seems unlikely to be a caching problem in an IBM i environment (indicated by the use of System i Navigator).

Comment: @WarrenT - DB2 can [cache dynamic SQL statements](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.apsg%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_dynamicsqlstmtcached.htm) to speed up execution time. It's possible that `SELECT *` was cached at some point. I will readily admit, though, that this is a bit out of my league.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 This is DB2 for i, not z/OS. ( [Dynamic SQL applications](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fsqlp%2Frbafydynmic.htm) ) But we don't know what release of IBM i, which could conceivably affect whether SQE or CQE was being used, and behavior in caching.  Either should notice the [replacement of the table object](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzatabl.htm).  But if it were caching for VB then why is it not doing the same for Navigator?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting, then recreating your ODBC connection.
Seems connections have "memory" and changes to the source aren't 
reflected in the connection file.